# Get Woocommerce Users with no orders AND not active since a year

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, phpmyadmin

I found the following SQL query to get customers with no first/last name and no posts:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`
FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'wp_capabilities' AND `meta_value` = 'a:1:{s:8:"customer";b:1;}') AND
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'first_name' AND `meta_value` = '') AND
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_name' AND `meta_value` = '') AND
`user_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'billing_first_name') AND
`user_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'billing_last_name') AND
`user_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_order_count' AND meta_value > 0);
```

However, I also want to filter customers who haven't had any activity (e.g. logged in) in over 12 months.

I am thinking using "last_update" parameter.

Can someone help guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following using "last_update" meta key:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`
FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'wp_capabilities' AND `meta_value` LIKE '%customer%') AND
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'first_name' AND `meta_value` = '') AND
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_name' AND `meta_value` = '') AND
`user_id` IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'last_update' AND `meta_value` < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))) AND
`user_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'billing_first_name') AND
`user_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'billing_last_name') AND
`user_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_order_count' AND meta_value > 0);
```

It should work.

Now you could replace in the code *(as I don't see any more `_order_count` meta key)*:

```sql
`user_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_order_count' AND meta_value > 0)
```

with:

```sql
`user_id` NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT `user_id` FROM `wp_usermeta` WHERE `meta_key` = 'paying_customer' AND `meta_value` = '1')
```